# Oracle Job does not work with tables under Oracle Label Security

Tags: oracle, jobs

I have a database schema MYUSER under Oracle Label Security (OLS) and a job MYUSER.MYJOB executing a procedure MYUSER.MYPROC, which selects from or updates  tables in the MYUSER schema. User MYUSER is DBA, he has full OLS privileges, he is the MYJOB and MYPROC owner and caller, but MYJOB does not work. It starts, calls MYPROC, procedure MYPROC begins, do nothing and ends in 0.01 second without any message.

But When I execute the same MYPROC from PL/SQL block, out of any job, it works very well. It seems that MYPROC executes with no access rights to MYUSER tables.

Could anyone tell me what may be the reason for this and put some light to solve this issue?

Comment: Is this DBMS_Jon or DBMS_Scheduler? Is there any information in the relevant job log table?

Comment: It's DBMS_SCHEDULER. ALL_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG view says 'SUCCEEDED'